# Why the length of the encrypted message is changed after downloading this message from file?Python RSA encryption/decryption

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, byte, rsa

Encryption

```
def encrypt():
k=0
l=1
length=len(message)/20
if int(length)>=1:
    for i in range(int(length)+1):
        message1=""
        if i<int(length)+1:
            i=k
            message1=""
            for j in range(20*i,20*(i+1)):
                message1+=message[j]
            k=i
            message1=message1.encode()
            print(len(message1))
            crypto = rsa.encrypt(message1, pubkey)
            text1.insert(END,crypto)
            cryptow+=crypto
        else:
            message1=""
            for i in range(len(message)-int(length)*20):
                message1+=message[int(length)*20+i]
            message1=message1.encode()
            crypto = rsa.encrypt(message1, pubkey)
            print(type(crypto))
            text1.insert(END,crypto)
            cryptow+=crypto
print(len(cryptow))
showinfo("Attention!","Message was encrypted")
```

message=2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71

> > print(len(cryptow)) in penultimate string=96

then i save the resulting cipher in the file:

```
def save_encrypt_message():
filename = asksaveasfilename()
save_encrypt_message = open(filename,'wb')
print(len(cryptow))
save_encrypt_message = save_encrypt_message.write(cryptow)
save_encrypt_message.close()
```

> print(len(cryptow)) still equally 96

After, i reran program and load cipher from file:

```
def open_message_for_decrypt():
filename = askopenfilename()
decrypt_message = open(filename,'rb')
decrypt_message = decrypt_message.readlines()
text1.delete('1.0', END)
text1.insert(END,decrypt_message)
print(len(decrypt_message))
```

and

> print(len(decrypt_message))
>   =1 So WHY?

Comment: Why all the `global`s?! Also, could you cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: 1).Because i have many functions.

Comment: That's why we have arguments and return values.

Comment: 2).I dont know where is problem, but i ll try

Comment: I need to return several values and i dont want to romp with arrays

Comment: It would be easier to cut down to a minimal example if you weren't using `global`s! Multiple return values are tuples, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line:

```
decrypt_message = decrypt_message.readlines()
```

a list is assigned to `decrypt_message`, where each item in the list is one line from the file; there's only one line in the file...